# How do I get the network manager applet and install openvn on Kali 2.0 Gnome 3?

Tags: kali-linux, gnome3, networkmanager, openvpn

I'm attempting to install VPN on my Kali Linux Gnome 3 laptop. I've followed the instructions on this page https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/18003/openvpn-step-by-step-setups-for-various-debian-based-linux-oss-with-videos-ubuntu-mint-debian

There is no network manager applet in my panel and whenever I try to start it in a shell with 'sudo nm-applet' I get:

(nm-applet:2858): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy

(nm-applet:2858): nm-applet-WARNING **: Failed to show notification: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files

My network-manager service is running btw. I look at the connection editor (nm-connection-editor) and the VPN is there but I cannot connect without the applet.
I've looked at various solutions but none seem to work.
If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: `nm-applet` wants to connect to the current user's dbus session. It is not supposed to be run as root.

Comment: That link no longer exists, but from the title it sounds like a general debian-based-distro instruction set. Kali is heavily modified -- and it is *not recommended for general desktop use* so if you're at all new to linux *please* consider using something else as your desktop distribution while you learn the ropes.

Answer (score -1):

here is the good way to install PIA on Kali 2.0 : https://fra.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/ubuntu-openvpn

Comment: 1) SE frowns on URL-only answers, because link rot is a thing. 2) That particular page only explains how to run a shell command specifically for PIA, which is not what the poster asked for.